# Making decision based on retrieved Data from Firebase - Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

Alright so I'm making an online donations portal android application. There will be 2 primary users of the application:

1. Donors
2. Charity Organisation Representatives

There is a different UI based on the user type.

Below is the sign up form:

[image]

Below is the sign in form:

[image]

And the data from the form is added to the database as follows (upon sign up):

[image]

Below is the authenticated user's data on firebase:
[image]

Below is the sign up class:

```
package com.example.android.edonate;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    //variables to store data from the form
    private EditText fname;
    private EditText lname;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText cellNo;
    private EditText password;
    private Spinner type;
    private Button signUp;

    //Firebase instance variables
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabaseReference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);

        //Initialize firebase components:
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        //to set to specific location within the database and storage
        mUsersDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users");

        //Initialize firebase authentication
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //to get data from the form:
        fname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname);
        lname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lname);
        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        cellNo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile_number);
        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        type=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.user_category);
        signUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sign_up_2);

        //Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
        signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                User user = new User(fname.getText().toString(), lname.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(), cellNo.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), type.getSelectedItem().toString());
                mUsersDatabaseReference.push().setValue(user);  //add user details to the database
                RegisterUser();

                //return to home page after signing up:
                //Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this,MainActivity.class);
                //startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    //to register user to the Firebase 'users'
    public void RegisterUser(){
        String Email = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String Password = password.getText().toString().trim();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Email field is Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Password)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password field is Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        try {
                            //check if successful
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                //User is successfully registered and logged in
                                //start Profile Activity here
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Couldn't register, try again",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

WHAT I WANT TO DO is open a different Activity based on whether the signed in user's 'type' (as shown in the database) is donor or charity. Hence the Following steps are needed in the sign in Class:
1. Verify user email and password (that I have already implemented)
2. Get the users record from teh database that has that particular email.
3. Check whether the 'type' field of the selected user record is 'Charity' or 'Donor'
4. Open relevant activity based on the value of type field

Steps 1 and 4 will be implemented easily. Steps 2 and 3 is what I need help with. Steps 2 and 3 will be Implemented in the SigIn.java class. Right now I am opening the DonorHome.java calss by default but I need to add a condition to open either Donor.Home and CHarity.Home

Below is the code for teh SignIn.java class. What is the relevant code I need to add here?:

```
package com.example.android.edonate;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.util.Log;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseError;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabaseReference;
    private Button signIn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_in);

        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mUsersDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        //.child("users");
        signIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sign_in_2);

        signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v == signIn){
                    LoginUser();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void LoginUser(){
        final String Email = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String Password = password.getText().toString().trim();
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    DonorHome.class));
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "couldn't login",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Comment: You can save `type` field in SharedPreference at the time of login (when you are first time identifying that which type of user is)  and check that value when you come again.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with tell you that StackOverflow doesn't birth for solution code requests, but for issue or doubts, so ask for many code lines is not so appropriate.

Anyway, you need to do something like this:

```
public void LoginUser(){
    final String Email = email.getText().toString().trim();
    String Password = password.getText().toString().trim();
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        getUserInformation();
                        //finish(); Don't finish activity now
                        //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            //  DonorHome.class)); Don't start activity without know user type
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "couldn't login",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
private void getUserInformation(){
//here get User information by firebase querying and get result.....
...onSuccess(){
    if(userType.equals("Donor")
        startDonorActivityMain();
    else
        startCharityActivityMain();
    }
}
```